# Postgresql разделитель в real

Tags: postgresql, преобразование-типов, db2

Пытаюсь подключить внешнюю таблицу из db2 к postgresql через odbc.
При подключении возникла проблема - не работают таблицы с типом данных float/double/real и т.п. потому что разделитель в db2 запятая, а postgresql использует точку.

Параметров для odbc на эту тему я не нашёл.
Собственно вопрос - можно ли как-то настроить postgresql, чтобы он воспринимал запятую как разделитель в float/double/real автоматически.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В DB2 тоже точка (везде точка). То, что вы видите запятую, это удобно-читаемое преобразование в символьный тип. Это преобразование зависит от национальных настроек, например, DB2 у вас в России, а PG в Америке. В эту сторону и ведите поиск.

Comment: действительно - сейчас проверил в db2 и преобразование идёт только с точкой.
Странно, что в db2 client и через odbc возвращается запятая

Answer (score 0):

`real` и `float` - это алиасы для типа `float4`. Для преобразования из текста [используется](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/float.c#L213) библиотечная функция `strtod`. В принципе, она зависит от локали, но у меня на локали `ru_RU.utf8` всё равно требует точку в качестве разделителя. Ваша локаль, очевидно, тоже.

`double` - соответственно `float8`, [используется](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/float.c#L412) так же стандартный вызов `strtod`.

Есть ещё тип данных `numeric` - но там уже [гарантированно](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c#L5653) только точка в качестве разделителя.

Так что если настройки локализации не помогают (`lc_numeric`) - то больше крутить в настройках `postgresql` уже нечего.

Comment: Собственно сейчас накопал lc_numeric, который выводит числа с запятой (it_IT.UTF-8), но с foreign table ничего не получается